# Rail 4: How to delete_all a query with a join result

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I´m trying to delete_all the results of a query with a join between two tables like:

```
availabilitiesToDelete = Mmk::Availability.find_by_sql(["SELECT a.id
                                              FROM mmk_availabilities a, mmk_resources r 
                                              WHERE a.resource_id = r.id
                                              AND r.company_id = ?", mmkCompany.id])              
              availabilitiesToDelete.delete_all
```

but I´m getting error

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `delete_all' for #<Array:0x007fa657f2a4e0>)
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

`find_by_sql` in rails-4 return `Array` object and not a `ActiveRecord::Relation` object. `delete_all` is AR query which will throw error in your case.

Perhaps you can proceed further as,

```
availabilitiesToDelete.each(&:delete)
```

Answer (score 0):

As ray has already pointed out in his answer, `find_by_sql` will return an `Array` on which you therefore cannot call `delete_all`.

However, you could use a second query to delete all the records at once without causing an n+q query like this:

```
Mmk::Availability.where(id: availabilitiesToDelete.map(&:id)).delete_all
```